# Help with calculating division with remainders on normal calculators.

Tags: calculator

I want to calculate 254 797 / 56
and when I use a calculator I get: 45478.5178571
basically I want to turn that .5178571 into the remainder.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply the mantissa (whatever is behind the decimal) back by your divsor:

$.5178571 * 56\approx 29$

You should round this answer because your calculator will most probably discard any periodic decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract your integer part, 45478, to be left with your fractional part, 0.5178571.  Then multiply the fractional part back by 56: .5178571*56.  I get 28.9999976, which should be 29 after you account for round off error.  If you want the remainder, you're safer doing it all by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Take away the largest whole number, in this case $45478$ and then multiply by $56$